# Outlook on WIndows 10 - mail styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, mailing

The button's background-color style doesn't work on Outlook email client, altough it works properly in other clients and browsers (and even on Outlook at MacOS too).

## Not Working:

[image: Not working example (Outlook on windows 10 view)]

## How it should look:

[image: How it should look like]

## The code:

```
<td align="right" valign="center" style="margin: 0; padding: 20px;" width="200">
    <a href="{{ company['url'] }}">
        <button style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #00A4FF; font-size: 12px;
            cursor: pointer; border: none; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;" >
            {{ translation._('company.view.emailTemplatesCompaniesOfUser.go') }}
        </button>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: I think buttons inside of anchors used to be invalid HTML in HTML 4.  Not sure if it'll work, but can you try replacing the `button` element with a `span` maintaining the same styles?  You may need to add `display:inline-block` though.

Comment: background is visible but other styles like padding don't work.

Comment: That'll be because `inline-block` is not supported.  I'll do a little digging.

Comment: Removing inline-block doesn't change anything, don't worry :)

Comment: Hm... Looks like the framework I use for emails uses inline-block on an anchor.  Maybe you can try the above code with padding applied to the button, but add you `background` and `color` to the anchor tag?

Comment: Have a look at https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design.  It looks like outlook is determined to collapse buttons.  The author has a solution but it involves using VML (ew...).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you could only use  element and get rid of the  element may help your solution. You can give background color to the table of that  element.

```
    <table  align="center" border="0"  width="100" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:0;padding:0px;margin:0px;width:300px;height:50px;border-radius: 3px;background: #00A4FF;text-align:center;">
           
           <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="center" style="margin: 0; padding: 20px;" width="200">
     <p style="padding:0px;margin:0px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-align:center;line-height:100%;letter-spacing:normal;color:#ffffff;">
 <a href="{{ company['url'] }}" style="color:#ffffff;border:0px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;display:block;width:100%;height:20px">

{{ translation._('company.view.emailTemplatesCompaniesOfUser.go') }}

                </a>
               </p>   
            </td>
        </tr>
    
    </table>
```